# in Ember how to pass in a parameter with link-to and use it in the rendered template?

Tags: ember.js, link-to

I have to links that render the same template but they have different labels. Depending on which link the user clicks on, I want to show different text on my rendered template. Is there anyway to do this?

```
{{link-to "new_post"}}
```

and in my new_post.hbs I want to use this parameter. Assuming the parameter name is isValid

```
{{#if isValid}}
  <h3> This is valid </h3>
{{else}}
  <h3> This is not valid </h3>
{{/if}}
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/#toc_link-to-helper

You can add query params to a link-to with this syntax:

```
{{#link-to 'posts' (query-params direction="asc")}}Sort{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: yes thank you. But this gives me an error. I googled around and turns out this is a bug in Ember.

Comment: You are probably receiving an error because query params are currently an experimental feature. You need the 'canary' version of Ember in order to use them, with the 'query-params-new' feature flag turned on. This link will explain further:

http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/feature-flags/